# How to extend rxjs to add my own Operator?

Tags: rxjs, typescript2.0

I'm using [rxjs (5.0+)](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) and i want to write a my own `Operator` with name `append` for `Observable`. Now i have successfully create the Operator and it works, but how to tell Typescript that the original Observable support my new Operator? because it complain a compile Error like below:

`Property 'append' does not exist on type 'Observable'.`

Following is my source code:

---

append.ts

```
Observable.prototype.append = function (value) {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
        const mapObserver = {
            next: (x) => observer.next(x == null ? value : x + value),
            error: (err) => observer.error(err),
            complete: () => observer.complete()
        };
        return this.subscribe(mapObserver);
    });
};
```

test.ts

```
import './append';

export class Test {
    init() {
        Observable.from([1, 2])
            .append('a') // <--- Compile error! but in fact, it works.
            .subscribe(function (x) {
                console.log(x); // Works, output 1a and 2a
            }
        );
    }
}
```

---

I know i need to tell Typescript about my new `Operator`, but i don't know how to do it? I have checked rxjs's source code and found that it contains following code in `src/add/operator/map.ts`. I have tried to add some similar code into my `append.ts`, but i don't know what's the module name that contain the `Observable` interface. (BTW, i'm using Typescript 2.)

```
declare module '../../Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    map: typeof map;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module name specified in your declaration merging should be the same as the module name that was used when you imported `Observable`. For example:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

...

declare module 'rxjs/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    map: typeof map;
  }
}
```